# 3 equations with 9 unknown variables with scalar product

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Excuse my bad english pls. I can't find a proper solution to my problem because i don't know the exact mathematical terms in english.

My problem is how to get the 3 elements of each of 3 vectors named u,v,w with the scalar products:

u°v = -5   u°w = -2 and v°w=9

when i've got the 3 vectors, i have to calculate:
((3u-v)°2w)-((5w-2v)°3u)

I dont really need a full solution unless you feel like giving me one, but a little hint how to solve this would be great.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake, the second part of the term is also a dot product-->edited

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to solve for the vectors (in fact, you can't because the system is so underdetermined). Just expand the expression they give you. $(3u-v)\cdot (2w) = 6u\cdot w - 2v\cdot w$. You have both of these values so you can compute this part. Do the same for the other term.